# Appears to be internal error in Fusion Tables...anybody know what's going on?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Earlier today, my map at http://oto-usa.org/locations/ was working fine. This evening, my red/yellow/blue paddle markers aren't showing up, and the mapped points don't respond when clicked. The javascript console in Chrome shoes the text below. I don't think this is anything I can fix. Anybody know what's going on?

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature?1sft%3A1JJ…253E%253E0&4m2&1sy&2s2&4m2&1stmplt&2s3&callback=*xdc*._f9b7oq&token=110983
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature?1sft%3A1JJ…%253E%253E0&4m2&1sy&2s2&4m2&1stmplt&2s3&callback=*xdc*._muaa3c&token=88839
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/LayersService.GetFeature?1sft%3A1JJ…%253E%253E0&4m2&1sy&2s2&4m2&1stmplt&2s3&callback=*xdc*._o9shd9&token=42697

Comment: Works for me now. Internal Server Error doesn't have to be a result of an error in your application, I assume a problem on google's side(note that FusionTableLayer is still experimental)

Comment: Yes, working for me again as well. Thanks for replying.